# Why is the permission of the created file inconsistent with the specified one?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am using `open` to create a file in `c`, here is my code

```
int create_file(const char* path)
{
    extern int errno;
    int fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL , 0666);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf(0, "open file failed %s, %d", path, errno);
    }
    return fd;
}
```

but I find the `permission` of the file is '0644' after I create it, I used `gdb` to step through like this:

```
e.c:32
32      int fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL , 0666);
(gdb) n
33      if (fd < 0)
(gdb)
```

we can see `0666` clearly, but I use `ll` command get this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 29 10:59 error_mmap_0.log
```

it is of `0644`, who can tell me why?

This question will cause that the child process can not open the file. If I open the file in `child process` after `fork`, I will get `errno 13` which mean `Permission denied`.

Comment: The mode you are using to open a file is in no way related to file system permissions.

Comment: Please do a `man 2 open`. It's very well described in the man page for the open call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`open(2)` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) explains:

> The effective mode is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode of the created file is (mode & ~umask).

So if you want to be able to set arbitrary permissions with the `open()` call, regardless of the current umask of your process, you have to first change the umask of your process with [the `umask()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html).

Alternatively you can also change the mode of the file after you've created it using [`fchmod()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fchmod.2.html), which is not affected by the umask.

Comment: *you have to first change the umask of your process with the umask() function.*  Note that it is impossible to avoid race conditions if you change a process's `umask` value using the `umask()` function - functions such as `creat()`, `open()` and `mkdir()` are all [async-signal-safe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).  The **only** race-condition-free way to get the exact permissions on a newly-created file or directory is with `[f]chmod()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle eeh, if a signal handler calls those functions and makes assumptions about the state of the umask, that feels like it's the signal handler's fault. a function being async-signal-safe doesn't mean you can just assume all the parts of the environment that influence the function's behavior are the same way they were when the process started or something like that. now if you had said "be careful with umask() if you have multiple threads", then I'd agree with you ;-)